# ¿Cómo definir la estructura para un JSON dinámico en C#?

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialize

estoy desarrollando una App que consume el servicio rest desde el sitio de un tercero. La respuesta que obtengo es un JSON, por lo que definí una estructura como clase en C#. El problema es que este JSON es dinámico, por ejemplo, hay un campo "afiliación" asociado a un "autor"; un autor puede tener una o más afiliaciones. Si en la estructura defino algo como:

```
public class Author
{
public Affiliation affiliation { get; set; }

...

} 


public class Affiliation
{
        public string country { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("@afid")]
        public string Afid { get; set; }

        ...
}
```

Solo me sirve para el caso de que el autor tenga una sola afiliación (por el formato que viene el JSON). Cuando intento deserializar un autor con más de una afiliación el programa se cae, mostrándome el siguiente error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'PubData.Model.AbstractRetrievalModel+Affiliation' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Cuando cambio la estructura para incluir una lista:

```
public class Author
{
public List<Affiliation> affiliation { get; set; }

...

}
```

El programa se cae mostrando el error contrario:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PubData.Model.AbstractRetrievalModel+Affiliation]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

La conclusión es que el servidor crea la estructura del JSON dependiendo de los datos disponibles, entonces, mi pregunta es ¿cómo podría abarcar ambos casos al mismo tiempo?

Lo que hice hasta ahora es definir la propiedad afiliación como un objeto:

```
public class Author
{
public object affiliation { get; set; }

...

}
```

Lo que me permite deserializar correctamente, pero creo debe haber una solución más "limpia" y por ende mejor.

Espero que se entienda mi pregunta, y me disculpo si uso un lenguaje poco técnico.

Edito: Aclaro que el JSON que obtengo no depende de mí y por tanto no puede ser modificado.

Desde ya muchas gracias, Saludos!!

Comment: suena a tema de reflection...

Comment: deberias colocar el json que te devuelve

Comment: El JSON es muuuuy largo, y como decía, cambia de una consulta a otra (va de 700 a más de 2000 líneas apróx). Logré crear la clase con todas las sub-clases correspondientes, pero no logro dar con una solución mejor para los casos que comenté.

Comment: Sean 700 o 2000, lo primero es definir la estructura descerializar, como es el json de entrada para cada caso?